# Association between Pseudo elements and Relative/Absolute Positioning

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, frontend, css-position

I would like to achieve a fading effect on the text of a card as shown in the following image:
[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1atVX.png)

To implement this effect, I have applied a linear gradient to the background of the pseudo-element of the text using the following CSS:

```css
.card-content .text {
    font-size: .9em;
    text-align: left;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.card-content .text:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient(to top, white, transparent)
}
```

However, the result I obtained is different from what I expected. The fading effect does not end at the bottom of the text content, but instead ends at the bottom of the "See More" button, as shown in this image
[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1rCPR.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q8th8.png)

I'm confused about this because the `text` and the `button` are separate elements, and I have applied the linear gradient style only to the pseudo-element of the `text`. My assumption is that the use of `position: absolute` on the text's pseudo element caused this issue because absolute positioning takes the element out of the document's flow. Is my assumption correct?

When I added `position: relative` to the `text` element as in the following CSS, I was able to achieve the desired look:

```css
.card-content .text {
   ** position: relative; **
    font-size: .9em;
    text-align: left;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.card-content .text:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient(to top, white, transparent)
}
```

However, I'm not sure why this fixed the problem. This made me wonder if, in general, when using pseudo-elements and applying absolute positioning to them, it is advisable to always use relative positioning on the original element. I would appreciate it if someone could explain this.

Here's the complete HTML and CSS code for reference:

**HTML**

```html
    <div class="card">
            <div class="card-img">
                <img src="imgs/img1.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="card-content">
                <p class="text">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                </p>
                <span class="see-more-btn"> See More </span>
            </div>
     </div>
```

**CSS**

```css
.card {
    position: relative;
    background: #fff;
    width: 350px;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 25px rgba(2, 2, 2, 0.25);
    border-radius: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.card .card-img {
    position: relative;
    width: 350px;
    height: 200px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.card .card-img img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.card-content {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 15px;
}

.card-content .text {
    **position: relative; **
    font-size: .9em;
    text-align: left;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.card-content .text:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient(to top, blue, transparent)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp), an absolutely positioned element is positioned relative to its nearest *positioned* ancestor, or if there is no such ancestor, it is positioned relative to the `<body>` element. A positioned element is one which has any value for `position` other than `position: static;`, which is the default value. To turn a non-positioned element into a positioned element without making any other change, style it as `position: relative;`.

This behaviour is consistent across **all** elements, including pseudo-elements.

In your case, when your `.text` element is **not** styled with `position: relative;` its absolutely-positioned child pseudo element (the gradient) is positioned relative to **the `.card-content` element**, which is its nearest *positioned* ancestor. Because this element contains both your `.text` and your `.see-more-btn`, the gradient ends up covering both of them.

When you do style `.text` with `position: relative;` your gradient is then positioned relative to `.text`, and therefore it covers only that.

Another solution would be to allow the gradient to cover all of `.card-content`, but bring `.see-more-btn` forward in the z-order so that it's on top of the gradient. `z-index: 9;` should do the trick. See this snippet for side-by-side cards showing first the problem, then your solution, then my solution.

```css
.card {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    background: #fff;
    width: 170px;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 25px rgba(2, 2, 2, 0.25);
    border-radius: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.card .card-img {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.card .card-img img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.card-content {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 15px;
}

.card-content .text {
    font-size: .9em;
    text-align: left;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.relative {
    position: relative;
}

.card-content .text::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient(to top, rgb(0,0,255,0.75), transparent)
}

.see-more-btn {
  background: #ff0000;
}
.in-front {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 9;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-img">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/500" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="card-content">
    <p class="text">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </p>
    <span class="see-more-btn"> See More </span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="card">
  <div class="card-img">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/500" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="card-content">
    <p class="text relative">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </p>
    <span class="see-more-btn"> See More </span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="card">
  <div class="card-img">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/500" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="card-content">
    <p class="text">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </p>
    <span class="see-more-btn in-front"> See More </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

My own preference would be to absolutely position the button as well, so that it can sit on top of the disappearing text, as demonstrated in this snippet.

```js
document.querySelector('.see-more-btn').addEventListener('click', evt => {
  evt.target.closest('.card-content').classList.add('expanded')
})
```

```css
.card {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    background: #fff;
    width: 350px;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 25px rgba(2, 2, 2, 0.25);
    border-radius: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.card .card-img {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.card .card-img img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}

.card-content {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 1px 15px;
    height: 150px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-align: justify;       
}

.card-content::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient(to top, rgb(255,255,255,0.94) 20%, transparent 75%)
}

.card-content p {
    font-size: .9em;
}

.see-more-btn {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 0 10px 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
}

.card-content.expanded {
  height: auto;
}

.card-content.expanded::before {
  background: transparent;
}

.card-content.expanded .see-more-btn {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-img">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/500" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="card-content">
    <p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc nec massa dui. Ut posuere sem arcu, quis mattis nibh interdum at. Nunc semper ligula metus, nec faucibus nisi viverra eget. Cras in ex in lorem vestibulum eleifend. Vestibulum accumsan massa ut urna fringilla, vel ultrices turpis consectetur. Phasellus congue justo lobortis, suscipit leo eu, lobortis velit. Vivamus posuere aliquet quam a rutrum. Duis sed erat facilisis, lobortis ex vitae, venenatis leo.
    </p>
    <p>
Nunc elementum volutpat felis, et luctus urna vulputate id. Praesent id tortor consectetur, malesuada enim in, ultrices sem. Suspendisse blandit auctor ex, volutpat facilisis lorem maximus non. Morbi sed nibh quis ipsum mollis cursus. Nulla congue eget augue id lacinia. Sed vestibulum felis massa, vel lobortis nunc bibendum vel. Nulla facilisi. Donec varius aliquam ex, sed ullamcorper massa iaculis a.    
    </p>
    <span class="see-more-btn"> See More </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Appreciate your response. However, I would like to clarify that I am already familiar with the information you provided. My main concern is to gain a better understanding of the relationship between positioning and pseudo elements in specific use cases like the one I've explained.

Comment: Pseudo elements are positioned in exactly the same way as normal elements. If you want a pseudo element to be positioned relative to its parent (the "original element", as you call it), then yes, you need to set `position: relative;` on the parent.

Comment: When using pseudo-elements and applying absolute positioning to them, it is advisable to use relative positioning on the selected original element?

Comment: Only if you want the pseudo element to be positioned relative to the original element.

Comment: Do you mind explaining: how styling "position: relative" to "card-content .text" fixes the issue of  linear gradient covering the "See More" button (when what I intended was to cover only up to the text)?

Comment: I have edited my answer to improve it ... hopefully that makes things clearer?

Comment: This clarifies a lot…!!! Thank you so much. Appreciate your willingness to take your time and energy to explain!